# Create a list of selected objects from S3 bucket with Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a S3 bucket with this structure:

```
data/date=1900-01-01-00/id=abc123def/file1.parquet
data/date=1900-01-01-00/id=ghi456jkl/file2.parquet
data/date=2021-07-11-00/id=mno789pqr/file3.parquet
data/date=2021-07-11-00/id=stu123vwy/file4.parquet
.
.
.
```

the files in the folder `date=1900-01-01-00` are dummy files, the others are "real file" coming from data acquisition.

I would like to create a list of `S3Objects` containing just the first dummy file and the first real file.

This is the code I wrote:

```
def __data_list(self):
    datastore_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(S3_DATASTORE_BUCKET)

    len_dummy_file = len(
        list(
            datastore_bucket.objects.filter(
                Prefix="data/date=1900-01-01-00/"
            )
        )
    )

    data_list = list(
        datastore_bucket.objects.filter(
            Prefix="data/"
        ).limit(len_dummy_file + 1)
    )

        
    return [data_list[0], data_list[-1]]
```

I can't know the number of dummy files and I could have thousands of real files, so read all the bucket could take a lot of time and I want to avoid it.

Does anyone know a better way to create the list?

Comment: Sorry, but your requirements are a little difficult to understand. Can you show us the output you would like for the sample list of files you have provided? Would it be `['data/date=1900-01-01-00/id=abc123def/file1.parquet','data/date=2021-07-11-00/id=mno789pqr/file3.parquet']`?

Comment: The list would be something like this: `[s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='data/date=1900-01-01-00/id=abc123def/file1.parquet'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='data/date=2021-07-11-00/id=mno789pqr/file3.parquet')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do logic on the `Key` returned from the object list:

```py
first_dummy = None
first_real = None

for object in s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).objects.filter(Prefix='data/'):
  if not first_dummy and 'date=1900-01-01-00' in object.key:
    first_dummy = object.key
  elif not first_real and 'date=1900-01-01-00' not in object.key:
    first_real = object.key

  if first_dummy and first_real:
    break

print(first_dummy, first_real)
```

Comment: Thanks John! I just modified a little bit your code so to assign to first_dummy and first_real the S3Object and not the object key: `first_dummy = object`.
Everything else is fine, thanks a lot!